# HTML JQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery

The code below is the function of the jquery

```
$(function() {
    $(".firstcal").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);
            $(".secondcal").datepicker("setDate", date);
        }
    });
    $(".secondcal").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    }).attr("disabled", 'disabled');
});
```

What i am trying to do is that when user choose 1 date from the first datepicker, it will update(+6 month) on 2nd datepicker , but unable to change the date anymore.(only first datepicker able to change)
and i need to insert it to database , is that possible?
as disabled it won't let me add to database

here the link: http://jsfiddle.net/vpfk6dce/

Comment: Inserting to databse using AJAX? PHP?

Comment: using php code to insert to db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a hidden input type then just add the date value to it. Then add it to database using `$_POST['hiddendate']`.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".firstcal").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);
            $(".secondcal").datepicker("setDate", date);
            $(".hiddendate").datepicker("setDate", date); //added
        }
    });
    $(".secondcal").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    }).attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    
    //added
    $(".hiddendate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

First Date:<input type="text" class="firstcal">
Last Date:<input type="text" class="secondcal">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddendate" class="hiddendate">
```